# sencha touch ios browser footer hide

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

In Sencha Touch, how do I get rid of ios bottom tab bar (as shown in this pic). I do not want to view the bottom bar which has options to bookmark, Add to Home screen etc options.
I want this to appear only when user scrolls down the view. I tried "autoMaximize : true" for `viewport` in `app.js`. It has many issues and wont even render the view on device browser.

I use 'Sencha Cmd v4.0.4.84' to build the app for production.
[image]

Comment: Are you deploying your Sencha Touch app as a web-hosted application, as opposed to a natively packaged application? This issue would only appear as a web-hosted application, and since iOS8 there is no *easy* solution for removing it (certainly nothing out of the box when it comes to Sencha Touch).

Comment: It's web hosted app and users can it to home screen. In either case bottom tab problem occurs .